# Error when domain and the problem to use durative-actions

Tags: pddl

I'm taking the [yb_drill_TBM2 example](https://github.com/oscar-lima/pddl_problems/blob/master/yb_drill_TBM2/domain.pddl) and converting it for use with a **time planner (POPF)**.

I am not able to identify the error can you help me?

### DOMAIN:

```
; Specification in PDDL1 of the rockin TBM2 drill test domain
; author : Oscar Lima, olima_84@yahoo.com

(define (domain idmind_agent)

(:requirements :strips :typing :fluents :negative-preconditions :disjunctive-preconditions :durative-actions )

(:types 
  location            ; locations in the arena, points of interest
  robot               ; your amazing yet powerful robot
  object              ; objects to be manipulated by the robot
  gripper             ; robot gripper
  robot_platform      ; platform slots for the robot to store objects
)

(:predicates

  ; robot ?r is at location ?l
  (at ?r - robot ?l - location)       
  ; object ?o is on location ?l
  (on ?o - object ?l - location)
  ; object ?o is stored on robot platform ?rp
  (stored ?o - object ?rp - robot_platform)   
  ; robot platform ?rp is occupied, yb has 3 free places to store objects
  (occupied ?rp - robot_platform)
  ; gripper ?g is holding object ?o
  (holding ?g - gripper ?o - object)
  ; gripper ?g is free (does not contain object)
  (gripper_is_free ?g - gripper)

)


; moves a robot ?r from ?source - location to a ?destination - location
; NOTE : the situation in which the robot arm is in any position before moving 
; is not handled at the planning level, hence we advise to always move the arm 
; to a folded position, then navigate
(:durative-action move_base
   :parameters (?source ?destination - location ?r - robot ?g - gripper)
   :duration (= ?duration 1)
   :condition (and (at start (at ?r ?source))
                   (over all (gripper_is_free ?g))
                 )
   :effect (and 
                  (at start (not (at ?r ?source)))
                  (at end (at ?r ?destination))
           )
)

; pick an object ?o which is inside a location ?l with a free gripper ?g 
; with robot ?r that is at location ?l
(:durative-action pick                                
   :parameters (?o - object ?l - location ?r - robot ?g - gripper)
   :duration (= ?duration 1)    
   :condition     (and    (at start (on ?o ?l))
                          (over all (at ?r ?l))
                          (at start (gripper_is_free ?g))
                  )
   :effect (and   (at end (holding ?g ?o)) 
                  (at start (not (on ?o ?l)))
                  (at start (not (gripper_is_free ?g)))
           )
)

; stage an object ?o in a robot platform ?rp which is not occupied with a gripper ?g 
; which is holding the object ?o
(:durative-action stage
   :parameters (?o - object ?rp - robot_platform ?g - gripper)
   :duration (= ?duration 1)
   :condition     (and    (at start (holding ?g ?o))
                          (at start (not (occupied ?rp)))
                          (at start (not (gripper_is_free ?g)))
                  )
   :effect (and   (at start (not (holding ?g ?o)))
                  (at start (gripper_is_free ?g))
                  (at start (stored ?o ?rp))
                  (at start (occupied ?rp))
           )
)

; unstage an object ?o stored on a robot platform ?rp with a free gripper ?g
(:durative-action unstage
   :parameters (?o - object ?rp - robot_platform ?g - gripper)
   :duration (= ?duration 1)
   :condition     (and    (at start (gripper_is_free ?g))
                          (at start (stored ?o ?rp))
                          (at start (not (holding ?g ?o)))
                  )
   :effect (and   (at start (not (gripper_is_free ?g)))
                  (at start (not (stored ?o ?rp)))
                  (at start (not (occupied ?rp)))
                  (at start(holding ?g ?o))
           )
)

; places and object ?o with a gripper ?g which is holding the object ?o
; with a robot ?r at a location ?l on robot_platform ?rp
(:durative-action drop_on_platform
   :parameters (?o - object ?l - location ?g - gripper ?r - robot ?rp - robot_platform)
   :duration (= ?duration 1)
   :condition     (and    (over all (at ?r ?l))
                          (at start (holding ?g ?o))
                          (at start (not (stored ?o ?rp)))
                  )
   :effect (and   (at end (gripper_is_free ?g))   ; the gripper is free
                  (at end (on ?o ?l))             ; object is now on location l
                  (at start (not (holding ?g ?o)))    ; the gripper is no longer holding the object
           )
)

)
```

### Problem:

```
(define (problem problem_1)

(:domain idmind_agent)

(:objects 
   dock S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 - location
   platform_middle platform_left platform_right - robot_platform
   idmind - robot
   o1 o2 - object
   robotiq - gripper
)

(:init 
   (at idmind dock)
   (on o1 S2)
   (on o2 S2)
(not (occupied platform_middle))
(not (occupied platform_left))
(not (occupied platform_right))
(gripper_is_free robotiq)
) 

(:goal
      (and  
            (on o1 S1)
            (on o2 S4)
      )
)

)
```

But I'm getting this error that I'm not being able to understand. I wonder if you can help me with what I'm missing.

```bash
rosrun rosplan_planning_system popf new.domain.pddl new_problem.pddl
Critical Errors Encountered in Domain/Problem File
--------------------------------------------------

Due to critical errors in the supplied domain/problem file, the planner
has to terminate.  The errors encountered are as follows:

Errors: 1, warnings: 9
new_problem.pddl: line: 11: Warning: Undeclared requirement :typing 
new_problem.pddl: line: 11: Warning: Undeclared requirement :typing 
new_problem.pddl: line: 11: Warning: Undeclared requirement :typing 
new_problem.pddl: line: 11: Warning: Undeclared requirement :typing 
new_problem.pddl: line: 11: Warning: Undeclared requirement :typing 
new_problem.pddl: line: 14: Warning: Undeclared symbol: at
new_problem.pddl: line: 15: Warning: Undeclared symbol: on
new_problem.pddl: line: 17: Warning: Undeclared symbol: occupied
new_problem.pddl: line: 20: Warning: Undeclared symbol: gripper_is_free
new_problem.pddl: line: 30: Error: Syntax error in problem file - types used, but no :types section in domain file.
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: `:negative-preconditions` and `:disjunctive-preconditions` are not supported by **POPF**, please refer to [POPF](https://planning.wiki/ref/planners/popf)

Comment: @Bilal why not answering the question instead of commenting?

Comment: @VictorPaléologue It seems to me too short to be an answer so I preferred to comment.